# Name pdf from custom field

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning, soql, attachment

i create quick action "generate and attach pdf". I need name pdf from custom field on opportunity object - Invoice_number__c(Auto_number). For example INV-000001.pdf. How i can do this? Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you're generating an `Attachment`, I would leverage the `Name` field there to set the name. You can query for the opportunity record in your function.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the same thing you are doing in your test class: query the opportunity with recordId.

```
Opportunity opp = [SELECT Invoice_Number__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :recordId];
//...
attach1.Name = opp.Invoice_Number__c;
```

Comment: that's work, thank you